# Set tabbar viewcontroller in app delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: iphone, tabbar, uiapplicationdelegate

this seems like a really easy thing to do, but for some reason I can't figure it out, and I'm not really sure what are the right keywords to ask.

I have tabbar set up, with 5 tabbar items.  In my app delegate, I'm trying to get the middle tabbar viewcontroller to be the viewcontroller to load up in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.  Right now the left tabbar viewcontroller is loading up.

How would I do this?  Is it something I can do in interface builder or can I do it programmatically too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this programmatically by adding the following line in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
```

This assumes that by "middle" you mean the one at index 2 (as in, you have objects at indices 0,1,2,3,4 in the tabBarController).